# Fetch recordonly if it has specific tags

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following sql query, to fetch unnoticed questions which contain no other tag than my favorite tags, plus it contains some more filters.

[**Live Demo**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/521400)

There are two major issues with this query (It might need more improvements though)

1. I have applied a bogus technique to achieve **in and only in**=> (You can see the query. I had to use same query twice first to get what i need and then to filter same results with a not other than filter, to ignore all questions which have any other tag than my favorite tags). I could not find any way else to do it.
2. I have applied `distinct` because it was giving me **duplicate results** even when i have not used any left join. How could I distinct Ids **without using distinct** keyword

---

```
Select distinct top 100  
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/'+Cast(p.Id as varchar(20)) as ids
from Posts p
Join posttags pt on p.Id=pt.PostId

where AcceptedAnswerId is null
and AnswerCount = 0
and len(body) <2000
and viewCount<30
and DateDiff(hour, p.creationDate, GETDATE())<200
and ClosedDate is null

and p.id not in

(
select p.id as id from posts p join posttags pt
on p.Id=pt.PostId
where pt.tagId != 21 and pt.tagId != 3
and pt.tagId != 9 and pt.tagId != 5
and pt.tagId != 820 and pt.tagId != 2
and pt.tagId != 22 and pt.tagId != 1508
and pt.tagId != 46426 and pt.tagId != 96
and pt.tagId != 363

and AcceptedAnswerId is null
and AnswerCount = 0
and len(body) <3000
and viewCount<30
and DateDiff(hour, p.creationDate, GETDATE())<200
and ClosedDate is null
)
order by ids
    
--21 mysql --3 javascript --9 c# --5 php --820 jquery
--2 html --22 sql --1508 json --46426 nodejs--96 asp.net
--363 ajax
```

Comment: Your query has unrequired complexity. I suggest you first simplify it (first thing that popped into my eyes was the list of `pt.tagId`s of the inner select, which could be written `pr.tagId not in (2,3,5,9,21,22,96,363,820,1508,46426)`). The second, is that the outer select is asking `not in` of what was returned by the inner, so you are actually asking for `p.id in (2,3,5,9,21,22,96,363,820,1508,46426)` plus other conditions, right?

Comment: Your first statement is correct, you second one isn't. Its not like minus minus equal plus , he wants only `ID` that has **only** those specific tags. So he need to check that there isn't any other tag other than that. @FDavidov

Comment: @sagi, if the inner returns 1,4,6,7,8... and the outer wants all but what the inner returned, then the outer wants 2,3,5,9..., right? (I'm ignoring here the other conditions of course).

Comment: Yes, he wants `2,3,5,9` **but** only if `1 or 4 or 6 or..` doesn't exists for the same `ID` .. @FDavidov , so `IN(2,3,6,9)` will return some undesired output .

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean, but never mind. Your answer satisfies his needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `HAVING` clause if the `ID` is the only column you need and `IN()` to avoid multiple conditions on the same column:

Check live demo here [**Response waiting questions**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/534403)

```
Select distinct top 100  
       'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/'+Cast(p.Id as varchar(20)) as ids
from Posts p
Join posttags pt 
 on p.Id=pt.PostId
where AcceptedAnswerId is null
    and AnswerCount <3
    and len(body) <2000
    and viewCount<30
    and DateDiff(hour, p.creationDate, GETDATE())<200
    and ClosedDate is null
GROUP BY 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/'+Cast(p.Id as varchar(20))
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN tagID IN(21,3,9,820,2,22,1508,46426,96,363) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

`COUNT(*)` will return the total number of records for this `ID` , the `SUM(CASE..)` will return the number of records without your undesired tags. If they are equal , it means that only desired tags exists.

Comment: Sorry, result is not meeting the requirement. Plz check 2nd last result here. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/534403. Its about android where i am not intrested in

Comment: Yes. Seems better. I am not very happy with group  by as it usually decreases the speed, but let me watch it more, it might be the best solution.

Comment: There is nothing bad with the `GROUP BY` clause, and its **a lot** better then having a second select like your `IN()` or a join/exists solution. If columns are properly indexed, everything should work fast , I doubt there is a faster solution without changing the logic. @Sami

Comment: Yes thanks, It is also working perfect for my next requirement (to include titles) as well. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/534418